# Storing links that may change in android app

Tags: android, google-play

Inside my android app I have hardcoded a link to some web service. Now every time the link to the web service changes, I need to make an update of the whole app through Goggle Play for changing this link.

Better would be if the application first connects to some other “static” web service and then gets the properly link that I can change whenever I want without an update.

Even better would be if it could be done somehow with Google Play, but I didn’t found any information for such a functionality.

Are there some suggested solutions to do that?

Comment: I think you answered your own question, get the link from a webservice but if that webservice changes you have to change that one too so not sure how much you gain by doing this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement GCM in your app and push notification with new url to all devices any time it changes. Then store that url in shared preferences / database on device.

Comment: That’s a nice solution, but it needs the user to register itself to enable GCM

Comment: What do you mean by "needs the user to register itself"? Device registration is simply done from java code and no user will be even aware of it existing.

Comment: Oh really? Then I misunderstood the GCM registration. Thanks for pointing me this out!